# Most consecutive turn overs for an NFL team in a single game

Tags: trivia, american-football, nfl

The New England Patriots hosted the Cleveland Browns on week 8 of the 2019 season. The Browns had 3 turnovers on 3 consecutive offensive plays. Nick Chubb fumbled on back to back Browns' plays, and Baker Mayfield threw an interception on the very next offensive play.

Seeing the browns turnover the ball in 3 consecutive snaps made me wonder how close they were to the record. I'd like to know what's the longest streak of consecutive offensive snaps that resulted in a turnover for a single team in one game. Please include the date, the team played against, and the nature of the turnovers (fumbles vs interception).